# activity monitor instruments ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, activity-monitor

i noticed that the activity monitor usage doesn't correlate with the allocations in instruments. I understand that this is due to the fact that allocations doesn't factor in a lot of things.

I was wondering how much memory should 1 app really use. I.e what is considered reasonable? In the allocations tool, my app is running at 2.0mb heap . In the memory monitor it sometimes peak to 50 before falling back to 40. Is that normal ? I understand that the iphone's have 128mb/256mb. Isn't 40 mb quite a lot for a simple app since safari seems to be using only 35mb heap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it does seem pretty high, but that depends on what actions your app performs when these peaks appear. Are you loading in a lot of graphics? sound?

Maybe you can give a little more information as to what your app does, and when these peaks appear

Comment: Basically the app takes pictures compresses them and sends to server.

Comment: I also noticed that the app crashes after taking the 60th image with a memory warning 65% + killing app.

Comment: it does sound like you are allocating to much, cant figure out the excact problem on the top of my head, but maybe you should look in to the file sizes and if possible release the already sent fotos from your memory, if possible

Comment: Hmm ok, I am using jpeg compression which returns NSData which is autoreleased by default .So not sure what I can do more. But am I supposed to be able to take an infinite amount of pictures? I am also rescaling images coming from the camera.

Comment: I also ran allocations and cannot see anything wrong there. Only peaks 2-3 mb and the UIImages only peak to 300-400kb.

Answer (score 0):

Images are usually stored in some place that does not get counted by instruments. You only see a small handle to the CGImageRef, etc. Apple needs to update Instruments (it would take quite a hack..) to also include memory like this.

EG: Load 1000px by 1000 px image at 4 bytes/px ==> 4MB, but you will see 50 bytes for some CGimageRef, or similar somewhere. So also count the CGImageRefs.